# Need to visit the Schengen zone from 1st to 8th of June, but my visa expires on the 4th. How should I apply for a new visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

My Schengen visa will going to expired on 4th of June. Since we have business meeting from 1st of june to 8th of June in Germany. Is there any way  re-apply my Schengen visa by cancellation the existing one. Will canceling my existing visa reflect poorly on me and hamper my future chances of traveling to the EU region.

Current visa valid for 6 months and 85 days staying permit. I stayed only 15 days in Germany.

Comment: You can also apply for a visa valid from 5 June, which seems to be the preferred way to go about this sort of thing.

Comment: As @phoog pointed out, you can apply for a time frame that gives back-to-back coverage so that you do not have to request a voluntary revocation.

Answer (score 3):

Simply apply for a new visa starting on the 5th of June. There's no need to cancel the existing one.